# How to find out the combinations of Views arguments that have the most Views result

Tags: 6, database, views

I have a node view with 2 arguments in URL `my-view/%1/%2`.

Both arguments %1 and %2 are Taxonomy Term ID.

I would like to make a page that lists the number of the View result per argument combination and order them by the number of the result.

For example, Something looking like this:

```
  %1 |  %2  | Resulst
  10 |  20  | 13
  10 |  21  | 7
  13 |  21  | 5
```

Is there anyway to make this kind of page?

My goal is to find out what the top 20 combinations of the 2 arguments that have the most nodes attached to.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by top 20 combinations. With two taxonomy terms you have 4 combinations: nodes with neither the terms, nodes with term A, nodes with term B, nodes with both the terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly do something like this in the crude but effective dull ax category:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu() {
  $items=array();

  $items['xyzzy'] = array(
    'title' => 'Two Tax Terms',
    'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_xyzzy',
    'access callback' => TRUE, 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  // any other custom menu items here

  return $items;

}

function YOURMODULE_xyzzy() {

  $first=array();
  $second=array();

  $matrix=array();

  // get all of the term ids on your system...

  $query=db_query('SELECT tid FROM {term_data}');

  while ($result=db_fetch_object($query)) {
    $first[]=$result->tid;
    $second[]=$result->tid;
  }

  // cycle through all of the possible permutations of a node tagged with both of them
  // (skip nodes tagged with both in opposite order, eg tagged with 1 & 2 == 2 & 1)

  $start=microtime(TRUE);
  foreach ($first as $f) {
    foreach ($second as $s) {

      $foo=0;
      $query=db_query('SELECT node.nid AS nid FROM node node INNER JOIN term_node term_node ON node.vid = term_node.vid LEFT JOIN term_node term_node2 ON node.vid = term_node2.vid AND term_node2.tid != %d WHERE (term_node.tid = %d ) AND (term_node2.tid = %d )', $f, $f, $s);
      while ($result=db_fetch_object($query)) {
        $foo++;
      }
      if ($foo && empty($matrix[$s . ' & ' . $f])) {
        $matrix[$f . ' & ' . $s]=$foo;
      }

    }
  }
  $stop=microtime(TRUE);
  $total=$stop - $start;


  arsort($matrix);

  $top20=array_slice($matrix, 0, 20);

  return '<pre>' . print_r($top20, true) . '</pre><pre>TOOK ' . $total . ' SECONDS</pre>';
}
```

but be prepared for a long wait if you have lots of terms.  Also, I just copied and pasted the second db_query sql out of Views when I ran out of memory calling one over and over inside those two foreach()'s so it's not using {table}s and all the other good stuff it could.

I am also sure there is a `COUNT(*)` sql construct that is much more efficient than my `$foo` but `$query->num_rows` isn't universally available as I found out when I tested this on a production site instead of just locally on my mac :)

Comment: and as an FYI, with 250 terms, this took about 8 secs to run locally on a mac and about 70 seconds on a pantheon hosted site so to say it's inefficient is being polite.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how to use this code? I created a custom module and then installed it but then what should I do? Sorry for my question but I'm not a coder ;)

Comment: this would be a page callback to a menu item defined in your module.  it is for drupal 6.  if you are running drupal 6, which you've tagged this with, I'll gladly flesh it out more, but if drupal 7, you're on your own as the sql calls are totally different there.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm on Drupal 6.  I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: I've added the menu hook you'd need.  Just copy and paste all of the code above into YOURMODULE.module (after the opening php :) and clear your caches and if all is good in the world you should be able to goto www.yourhost.com/xyzzy and see the results :)

Comment: Thaks a lot. I tried it but due to the timeout I couldn't get it work as I have a few thousand terms. So I'll make a local copy site and try it again.

Comment: Yeah, 1000 items will result in 1000 x 1000 or a million queries :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside Drupal, this would take some real custom magic. But, let's say for example, you wanted to show

pets/birds,

pets/cats

both birds and cats would be arguments off the main Views page of pets. BUT - if you had a Google Analytics account, which does not understand Drupal arguments, you could easily decipher which page received what number of visitors.

Because Google will never discriminate vs what is a page and what is an argument, you can easily see what would be most popular as a result.

Comment: Thanks. but there seems to be some misunderstanding. "Result" I'm talking about is not the result of page visitors but the result of View (the number of nodes in my case). I also change the tilt of this question a bit.